# writing negative numbers in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

2 – (-12/x) = -4

the negative 12 is what is confusing me. where do I put the negative sign?

```
(define (math x)
( = ( - ( / 12 x) 2) 4))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The negative symbol is a part of the number itself, you write it like you would in any other language:

```
(define (math x)
( = ( - ( / -12 x) 2) 4))
```

Output:

```
> (math 2)  ; 2-(-12/2) = -4 -> 2-(-6) = -4 -> 2 + 6 = -4 -> 8 = -4 (FALSE)
#f
> (math -2) ; 2-(-12/-2) = -4 -> 2-(6) = -4 -> -4 = -4 (TRUE)
#t
```

Comment: Also note that if your programming language doesn't support negative numeric literals, you can still get at negative numbers by subtracting from zero.  Example: `(- 0 12)` gets us `-12`.  Professional Racket will support the shorthand: `(- 12)` to negate `12` as well.  Note that Beginner Student Level language variants will insist that `-` be used with at least two arguments.